# How to solve error about neo4j ：Invalid input 'UNIQUE': expected "(", "allShortestPaths"

Tags: neo4j, load

I try to execute this comnands, but screen show the message: How to solve this problems?

```
Invalid input 'UNIQUE': expected "(", "allShortestPaths" or "shortestPath" (line 4, column 8 (offset: 269)) "CREATE UNIQUE(s1)<-[:FROM]->(r)"
```

initial input comnand:

```
:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500 load csv with headers from "https://lovecandyhsu.neocities.org/relations.csv" as csvLine MATCH (s1:Station { id: toInteger(csvLine.fromId)}),(r:Route { id: toInt(csvLine.route_informationId)}),(s2:Station { id: toInt(csvLine.toId)}) CREATE UNIQUE(s1)<-[:FROM]->(r) CREATE UNIQUE(r)<-[:TO]->(s2) RETURN csvLine
```

Answer (score 2):

The 'CREATE UNIQUE' clause was [deprecated in Neo4j version 3.2](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/deprecations-additions-removals-compatibility/)

The [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) caluse does the trick now.

Ideally, you should be good to go just by replacing 'CREATE UNIQUE' with 'MERGE'.